# Magento 2.1.9 static files not generating on production - leaves admin blank (no styles, no scripts loading)

Tags: magento2, magento2.1

Upgraded to Magento 2.1.9 from 2.1.8.

**Steps to replicate:**

Deploy in production mode

```
deploy:mode:set production
```

Set the following paths to 0 within db:

```
dev/template/allow_symlink
dev/js/merge_files
dev/js/enable_js_bundling
dev/js/minify_files
dev/css/merge_css_files
dev/css/minify_files
```

Set the following paths value to 1:

```
dev/static/sign
```

Deploy static assets:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_AU en_US && php bin/magento c:f
```

**Results**
Go to *mydomain.com/admin* and see:
[image: No admin styles or scripts loading]

Inspect this, what do we find:
[image: Throwing up 404s trying to load static minified files]
A bunch of 404s to static minified files, visiting these files in from CLI also confirms they actually don't exist.

I thought that it might be a locale issue, [saw this article](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137762/magento2-1-not-loading-css-js-and-admin-panel-after-installation) but this didn't work for me.

I have minification turned off in my settings, all caches cleared (including Varnish). Yet this issue still persists. Front-end appears fine on the other hand.

Any help would be much appreciated, otherwise I suppose I could train the client to edit the db directly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a dirty fix whilst I continue to look at a more permanent solution. Create a permanent redirect pointing from my custom adminhtml theme - the one that doesn't get deployed to the "Magento" theme which does exist:

```
rewrite ^/adminhtml/<CUSTOM_THEME>/backend/(.*)$ /adminhtml/Magento/backend/$1 permanent;
```

In my case I am using nginx. If anyone else is experiencing this issue I hope this will provide a temporary solution for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

If you have install magento2.x in your local PC then if you can try to change line #607.

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

to

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Open your console/terminal, and type these commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

It's working fine.

if you can try it....

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vikas but I have already tried this and it didn't work.